# Very specifically customized sections and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I just became an editor for a bi-monthly Newsletter and we have built XeLaTeX code to generate the
newsletter. This Newsletter was previously generated using Microsoft Word.  We want to maintain
the organization of Newsletter as was previously done, but we want to do it with (Xe)LaTeX instead
of Microsoft Word. I want to optimize our XeLaTeX code to make formatting easier.

Here is how the Newsletter is organized.  There is a title banner, followed by some text
and then there is a table of contents. The table of contents only lists the title of the topics
as a numbered list.  There are no page numbers in the table of contents.  Then there is a
Calendar of events which are listed and then there is a listing of all information related to
the Topics.  These should be numbered appropriately, and match up to the topic titles in the table
of contents.  Currently I am setting the numbers of the topics manually.  I would like XeLaTeX to
automatically generate the numbers of the topics and also the table of contents in exactly the
place I want it, near the top of the PDF file. I would like to use something like `\section` to
give the information such as Title1, personA, etc., and I want XeLaTeX to generate the numbers.

Here is a sample organization of the Newsletter.

```
O P S F N E T - Volume 22, Number 3 - May 15, 2015

...

Topics:
  1.  Title1
  2.  Title2
  3.  Title3
  4.  ...
  9.  ...
 10.  Title10

Calendar of Events:

...

Topic #1 ---- OP-SF Net 22.3 ---- May 15, 2015

From: personA
Subject: Title1

...

Topic #2 ---- OP-SF Net 22.3 ---- May 15, 2015

From: personB
Subject: Title2

...

Topic #3 ---- OP-SF Net 22.3 ---- May 15, 2015

From: personC
Subject: Title3

...
...
...

Topic #10 ---- OP-SF Net 22.3 ---- May 15, 2015

From: personC
Subject: Title10

...
```

Sample XeLaTeX for Newsletter:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}

\oddsidemargin 0.00cm
\textwidth 16.4cm
\textheight 24.0cm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont{LucidaSansRegular.ttf}[
   BoldFont = LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf,
   ItalicFont = LucidaSansItalic.ttf ]

\noindent
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}
{\large O\ P - S\ F\ \ N\ E\ T - Volume 22, Number 2 - May 15, 2015}\\[0.6cm]
\end{center}

\normalsize

\begin{center}
$\{$ Contents of Newsletter header $\}$
\end{center}

\small
\noindent Topics:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Topic Title 1\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 2\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 3\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 4\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 5\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 6\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 7\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 8\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 9\\[-0.75cm]
\item Topic Title 10
\end{enumerate}

\small
\vspace{0.2cm}
\noindent {\bf Calendar of Events:}
\vspace{0.3cm}\\
$\{$ Contents of Calendar of Events $\}$

\vspace{0.4cm}

\large
\noindent Topic \#1\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad OP- SF Net 22.2%
\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad
March 15, 2015
\small

\vspace{0.4cm}
\noindent From: Person A1\\
Subject:~Topic Title 1\\[-0.0cm]

\noindent $\{$Contents of Topic 1$\}$

\vspace{0.4cm}

\large
\noindent Topic \#2\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad OP - SF Net 22.2%
\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad
March 15, 2015
\small

\vspace{0.4cm}
\noindent From: Person A2\\
Subject:~Topic Title 2\\[-0.0cm]

\noindent $\{$Contents of Topic 2$\}$


\vspace{0.4cm}

\large
\noindent Topic \#3\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad OP - SF Net 22.2%
\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad
March 15, 2015
\small

\noindent $\vdots$
\vspace{0.4cm}

\large
\noindent Topic \#10\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad OP - SF Net 22.2%
\quad\rule[0.75mm]{15.5mm}{1.0pt}\quad
March 15, 2015
\small

\vspace{0.4cm}
\noindent From: Person A10\\
Subject:~Topic Title 10\\[-0.0cm]

\noindent $\{$Contents of Topic 10$\}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

\large
\noindent Thought of the month

\small

\vspace{0.4cm}
\noindent “Some quote.”  by Someone Else

\end{document}
```

Comment: A Minimum Working Example of what you've tried would be very useful.  As it is, you leave all the work to those trying to help you.  I might suggest the `tocloft` package for the table of contents, where an invocation of `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}} ` will prevent the page numbers from being set with the section names.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Hi Steven B. Segletes, I have added some sample XeLaTeX code to support my question.